# how to filter by item sku in order woocommerce api?

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

I need filter orders by items with some sku. Here is my code where im filtering by status:

```
$params = array( 'status' => 'processing' );
return $wc_api->get_orders($params);
```

there is response of return :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [orders] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] =&gt; 30
                    [order_number] =&gt; 30
                    [status] =&gt; processing
                    [line_items] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] =&gt; 1
                                    [subtotal] =&gt; 40.00
                                    [subtotal_tax] =&gt; 0.00
                                    [total] =&gt; 40.00
                                    [total_tax] =&gt; 0.00
                                    [price] =&gt; 40.00
                                    [quantity] =&gt; 1
                                    [tax_class] =&gt; 
                                    [name] =&gt; automobilis1
                                    [product_id] =&gt; 4
                                    [sku] =&gt; sku111111
                                    [meta] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

        )

)
```

there is doc :
https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

how to filtering order where items has sku ex. 123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce REST API doesn't provide filtering by sku.

But you can process list of orders after receiving it from API.

Like this:

```
$result = array();
$params = array( 'status' => 'processing' );
$api_result = $wc_api->get_orders($params);

foreach ($api_result->orders as $order) {
     foreach ($order['line_items'] as $item) {
         if ($item->sku == "123") {
             $result[] = $order;
             break;
         }
     }
}

return $result;
```